# Display one value pair from JSON object

Tags: json, react-native, location, expo

I'll preface this saying I'm a UX Designer that's new to React.

I'm using Expo/React-Native and using the "Location" feature to get the device's location information. I'm able to get the information back in a JSON object by using:

```
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");
class Explore extends Component {
 static navigationOptions = {
header: null
};

state = {
locationResult: ""
};

componentDidMount() {
this._getLocationAsync();
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== "granted") {
      this.setState({
        locationResult: "Permission to access location was denied"
      });
    }

let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
let geocode = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location.coords);
this.setState({ locationResult: JSON.stringify(geocode) });
  };
```

And in my render I'm calling the value using:

```
    <WelcomeText>
            Discover {this.state.locationResult}
          </WelcomeText>
```

Which returns the object:

```
[{"street":"Stockton St","city":"San Francisco","region":"CA","country":"United States","postalCode":"94108","isoCountryCode":"US","name":"1 Stockton St"}]
```

But how do I go about just displaying the value of "City" that's in the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<WelcomeText>
     Discover {this.state.locationResult[0].city}
</WelcomeText>
```

Explanation:

Your `this.state.locationResult` is an array of objects. With `this.state.locationResult[0]` we are accessing the first object. Then we can use the `.` operator to access the property we want. In your case `.city`

**Edit:** 
You need to pass in geocode without stringifying it, otherwise you cannot access it like i described it above. `reverseGeocodeAsync` is already returning an array of objects, no need to transform it to a string.

Replace:

```
this.setState({ locationResult: JSON.stringify(geocode) });
```

with:

```
this.setState({ locationResult: geocode });
```

**Edit2:**

Here is a working example: https://snack.expo.io/B1SqSd3iN

Comment: Got you. For some reason it is showing that it's a null value. Even when I use console.log(this.state.locationResult) the console log shows: 

"null
[{"street":"Stockton St","city":"San Francisco","region":"CA","country":"United States","postalCode":"94108","isoCountryCode":"US","name":"1 Stockton St"}]"

I'm not sure why it's returning a null value before returning the location info.

Comment: Does it matter if I'm setting locationResult to null in state?

state = {
    locationResult: "test"
  };

Comment: and console just returns "[" when i ask it to log this.state.locationResult[0]

Comment: I understand your answer but {this.state.locationResult[0].city} is coming back undefined. {this.state.locationResult} now comes back with:


Array [
  Object {
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "country": "United States",
    "isoCountryCode": "US",
    "name": "1 Stockton St",
    "postalCode": "94108",
    "region": "CA",
    "street": "Stockton St",
  },
]

Comment: It returns "undefined" and then the object.

Comment: undefined
Object {
  "city": "San Francisco",
  "country": "United States",
  "isoCountryCode": "US",
  "name": "1 Stockton St",
  "postalCode": "94108",
  "region": "CA",
  "street": "Stockton St",
}

Comment: @JasonTremain i've added a working example in my answer. This should now really resolve your issue.